# Using C# MVC4 and Matching DbContext Class name with ConnectionString name to use the right database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using EF Code First, I know that I have to match my `DbContext` class name with the database's connection string `name` attribute to make them work together. But the following code does not work:

```
 public class UserDbContext : DbContext
         {
             public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
         }
```

along with this connection string:

```
<add name="UserDbContext" 
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
 AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But instead I end up having to use this connection string instead, which points directly to the model along with the `DbContext` name

```
<add name="NextFlicksMVC4.Models.userAccount.Users+UserDbContext"     
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
 AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It works as intended, I connect to a LocalDB in the App_Data Folder.

Can anyone explain to me why it only works when I point it to the full path of the DbContext class?

Comment: I would Imagine its got something to do with the naming convention. You naming your connection string with the same name as your DbContext. Try chaning the connection name to something else, I think its just coincidence that when your adding the full name that its working.

Comment: @Derek So if I change my Connection name to FooBar, what exactly do we expect to happen? I assume it will use the default connection as before.

Comment: Te two connection strings you have listed are identical barring the name.

Comment: Right, which is the point. In the past as long as the connection name in Web.Config and the dbContext derived class had the exact same name, things were golden. For some reason in this case it is not so.  Also in the past my dbContext class has been unable to use any connection entry other than DefaultConnection unless the names  match exactly.

Comment: I have a site set up on Azure CLoud, I'll look at this when i get home.

Comment: @sec_goat This is interesting. I've set up many sites with Code first DALs and naming the connection string as the class of the DbContext has never been a problem. I've seen it working when the DbContext lives inside and outside of the calling assembly. Can you describe your setup in more detail (e.g. architecture, projects, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor, from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679577%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> Constructs a new context instance using conventions to create the name
>   of the database to which a connection will be made. By convention the
>   name is the full name (namespace + class name) of the derived context
>   class. For more information on how this is used to create a
>   connection, see the remarks section for DbContext.

From the remarks section for DbContext:

> If the parameterless DbContext constructor is called from a derived
>   context, then the name of the derived context is used to find a
>   connection string in the app.config or web.config file.

If you use a decompiler to look at the code for the default constructor in `DbContext`, you'll see it calls `GetType().ToString()` on the `DbContext` instance and uses that value to find the connection string. So it makes complete sense why the fully-qualified type name of your `DbContext` is a valid convention to use for naming your connection string.

In your example, `UserDbContext` is not the proper name because it is a nested class. You can leave off the namespace but at a minimum you will have to name your connection string `Users+UserDbContext`. If you want to have the connection string match the class name alone, you can't nest it inside your model.

Answer (score 4):

Specify a constructor in UserDbContext class like this and will solve the issue

```
        public UserDbContext() : base("UserDbContext") {}
```